# AccessDenied: Not authorized to perform rds:DescribeDBInstances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, rds

I'd like to programmatically list my RDS database instances and cluster snapshots, so I've attached the following IAM policy directly to one of my users:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ReadProdSnapshotsAndInstances",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds:DescribeDBInstances",
                "rds:DescribeDBClusterSnapshots"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I execute the following as that user (using the AWS Node.js SDK)...

```
rds.describeDBInstances({}, (error, data) => {
    ...
});
```

...I get the following error:

```
AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:iam::<accountId>:user/<userName> is not authorized to perform: rds:DescribeDBInstances
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? This seems like it should be so simple.

Comment: Are there any other polices attached to that user with an explicit deny for rds actions?

Comment: No, there are no other policies attached. And if I attach the built-in `AmazonRDSFullAccess` policy, my code works as expected.

Comment: Does it work if Action is "rds:Describe*"?

Comment: How are you authenticating to AWS? I faced the same issue using Cognito, and found that by default Cognito enhanced authentication doesn't allow access to RDS, you have to use basic auth. I posted my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67761849/iam-permission-issue-when-using-cognito-unauth-role/67789030#67789030

Answer (score 2):

You policy is correct for displaying RDS instances and cluster snapshots. Post your entire code so that we can see what the issue is. Also double check your usage of credentials.

Note: I did not test Aurora only RDS SQL Server.

I ran your policy thru the IAM Policy Simulator. `DescribeDBInstances` and `DescribeDBClusterSnapshots` passed while other commands failed.

I created a new user "testusers3". I attached your policy to this user.

I downloaded the credentials for this new user and created the profile "testusers3" using the AWS CLI.

The AWS CLI command `aws --profile testusers3 rds describe-db-instances` works correctly. Other commands such as `aws --profile testusers3 rds stop-db-instance --db-instance-identifier XXX` fail correctly.

Then I wrote the following Python program to test. This program can correctly display our RDS instances.

```
import boto3
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='testusers3')
client = session.client('rds')
r = client.describe_db_instances();
for i in r['DBInstances']:
        print(i['DBInstanceIdentifier'], i['DBInstanceClass'], i['Endpoint']['Address'])
```