# IAM permission issue when using Cognito UnAuth role

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I'm making a simple React app to access RDS data via DescribeDBInstances API. I want to allow public access, so I'm using Cognito with Unauthenticated access enabled.

I have the following policy attached to the provided UnAuth role, yet I'm still getting the following error when trying to use the RDS API from JavaScript (nodejs):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "rds:DescribeDBInstances",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::(account):assumed-role/Cognito_TestUnauth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: rds:DescribeDBInstances on resource: arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:(account):db:*
```

I redacted my account ID.

Also this default policy is attached:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
                "cognito-sync:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's my calling code:

```js
import { RDSClient, DescribeDBInstancesCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-rds";
import { CognitoIdentityClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity";
import { fromCognitoIdentityPool } from "@aws-sdk/credential-provider-cognito-identity";

// see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-rds/index.html
export default async function getDbInstances() {
    const region = "us-east-1";
    const client = new RDSClient({
        region,
        credentials: fromCognitoIdentityPool({
          client: new CognitoIdentityClient({ region }),
          identityPoolId: "(my identity pool ID)",
        })
    });

    const command = new DescribeDBInstancesCommand({});
    return await client.send(command).DBInstances;
}
```

I'm going a bit crazy here, it seems everything is set up correctly. What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer inside the IAM Roles documentation for Cognito: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html (see "Access Policies" section)

Enhanced authentication is recommended for Cognito and enabled by default, but since it uses the GetCredentialForIdentity API under the hood, access is limited to certain AWS services regardless of IAM policy (RDS isn't an allowed service). I didn't see any way to override this limitation.

The solution is to switch to basic authentication (you have to enable it first in the Cognito identity pool settings). Here's my working nodejs code to use basic auth and then fetch the RDS instances:

```js
import { RDSClient, DescribeDBInstancesCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-rds";
import { 
    CognitoIdentityClient, 
    GetIdCommand ,
    GetOpenIdTokenCommand
} from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity";
import { getDefaultRoleAssumerWithWebIdentity } from "@aws-sdk/client-sts";
import { fromWebToken } from "@aws-sdk/credential-provider-web-identity";

const region = "us-east-1";
const cognitoClient = new CognitoIdentityClient({ region })

// see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-rds/index.html
export default async function getDbInstances() {
    const { Token, IdentityId } = await getTokenUsingBasicFlow();
    const client = new RDSClient({
        region,
        credentials: fromWebToken({ 
            roleArn: "arn:aws:iam::(account id):role/Cognito_RDSDataAppPoolUnauth_Role",
            webIdentityToken: Token,
            roleSessionName: IdentityId.substring(IdentityId.indexOf(":") + 1),
            roleAssumerWithWebIdentity: getDefaultRoleAssumerWithWebIdentity()
         })
    });

    const command = new DescribeDBInstancesCommand({});
    return (await client.send(command)).DBInstances;
}

async function getTokenUsingBasicFlow() {
    const getIdCommand = new GetIdCommand({ IdentityPoolId: "us-east-1:(identity pool id)" });
    const id = (await cognitoClient.send(getIdCommand)).IdentityId;
    const getOpenIdTokenCommand = new GetOpenIdTokenCommand({ IdentityId: id });
    return await cognitoClient.send(getOpenIdTokenCommand);
}
```

Here's the documentation for the basic authentication flow vs enhanced that I followed to write my implementation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html